# sc is sharkContext in spark shell (DSE)

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have setup DSE 4.7.0 with

SPARK_ENABLED=1

in `/etc/default/DSE`, but when I start the spark shell (dse spark) even though I get no errors and see

Spark context available as sc.

then I find the variable sc is not a sparkContext:

```
scala> sc
res5: shark.SharkContext = shark.SharkContext@61cb67f1
```

Is something misconfigured? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
David

Comment: The first line should read "I have setup DSE 4.7.0 with"

Comment: You can edit your question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks Dan! I found the editor.

Comment: How are you starting your Spark Shell?

Comment: From the command line: 

`$ dse spark`